# How much does speed decrease with called argument size? (C/C++)

Tags: c, struct, stack

I have to make a decision which will be very important in future development of my application, so it must be perfect.

**The actual question:**

For easiness sake it is better to have additional 20 empty bytes, but that seems extremely inefficient. How far is my program affected when I pass a 50 bytes big struct to a function ? =P

**And why I am asking:**

I run 64bit. That means `8` bytes per variable.
Currently `stuff_s` is `3*8=24` bytes big.

- Just add three/four more variables, but bloat the struct size and slow down function calling.
- or to choose sometime pretty complicated but safe additional bytes (and RAM space).

I will be using these `stuff_s`s to contain data objects of any kind in a tree, they can handle an object or module(that is something specific, ignore modules). Data object size can be different... They might even be several Gigabytes to usual structs used. Now I don't want every damn struct to carry around additional 50 bytes. If that could be only one byte, or not more than 8... =(

I have a struct:

```
//
// stuff reference (either module or object)
//
struct stuff_s
{
    char s; // stuff: 'm' || 'o'
    union {
        struct {
            mfunc_t *fs;
            ppackage (*knockf)(ppackage p);
        } m;
        struct {
            void *h;
            size_t s;
            // HERE should the additional variables go.
        } o;
    };
};
```

Comment: Pass by reference rather than by value and it's a complete non-issue. (And if you can't pass by reference then you shouldn't tag your C questions `c++`.)

Comment: Even if you're using C, you can pass pointers rather than passing structures by value.

Comment: Its more like general sensefullness, the one or the other. Sorry for the weird title.

Comment: as always with performance: measure instead of guessing. Especially if you need a perfect answer.

Comment: Re: *I have to make a decision which will be very important in future development of my application, so it must be perfect.* I know, respect the person asking the question, yadda yadda, but ... ROFL, sorry.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- Donald Knuth

Comment: Part of the art of programming is delaying decisions. If something needs to be decided now and the impact is unclear, then decide now, but make it easy for anyone (yourself months or years down the line, or someone else) to change later.

Comment: +1 to cancel out whoever downvoted... everyone has to start from somewhere

Comment: "I have to make a decision which will be very important in future development of my application": this is how projects die before they begin. Managers want to make such decisions and don't realize that software development is all about flexibility.

Comment: +1 for @AlexandreC. 'software development is all about flexibility'.  If in doubt, use pointers and dynamic allocation. The size of objects rarely shrinks during development and references sound really nice but are actually just unsuitable for some tasks, (I am reseating pointer vars all the time during inter-thread comms).  It's all wery well mumbling on about premature optimization but, when it's realized that the performance of an app is undeliverable, it's too late to change a basic design decision.

Comment: @Martin : "*If in doubt, use pointers and dynamic allocation.*" Whaaa? I wish I could downvote comments. Allocation has nothing to do with argument passing.

Comment: 'Allocation has nothing to do with argument passing' - really?  How do you usually communicate a stream of 1MB buffers from one thread to another?

Comment: OK guys come on, there were 2 parts to this question. The first is about passing by reference, the second was he was worried about having a bunch of variables (20+) in his object to define what it was, like 'spare variables' for the future. he just needed an easy generic programming pattern (which I provided in the answer) to solve that. As for premature optimization, I think it's hard for us to really know exactly what his case is. Overly broad generalizations about how to program are much more harmful than premature optimization (and no I can't keep my irony in check)

Comment: @OrgnlDave yes, exactly :D ! You won't even believe how much generic the design should be. I wish I had only modules, but I wont get around objects =(. (assume every architecture should derive from one rule and spread towards that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use references.

C++:

```
void foo(stuff_s &what)
{
  what.o.s = 4;
}

int main()
{
  stuff_s SetToFour;
  foo(SetToFour);
}
```

C:

```
void foo(stuff_s *what)
{
  if (what == NULL) return;
  what->o.s = 4;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  stuff_s SetToFour;
  foo(&SetToFour);

  return 0; /* Because it's main in a strict C compiler. Ignore this. */
}
```

As to the design of your program, if your data is really, really unknowable, I would recommend using a void * pointer and an object type tag, or derive a class from a base class.

C++:

```
class base {
  public:
    int a;
    virtual void do_whatever();
    virtual int get_type() = 0; // Grab our type ID
};

class derived : public base {
  public:
    int b;
    float c;
    char *d;
    virtual void do_whatever() { c = 4.0F; }
    virtual int get_type() { return 1; }
};

struct stuff_s {
//    ...in o
  base *futs;
}

// Later on...
stuff_s foo;
switch (foo.o.futs->get_type()) {
  case 0: // Base class
    break;
  case 1: // Class type 'derived'
    derived *a = dynamic_cast<derived *>(foo.o.futs); // Dynamic cast lets us take a pointer to a base type and make it into a pointer to a derived type. Using our tag ID that we get from the virtual function, we can determine exactly which type to do.
    a->b = 4;
    break;
}
// This is roughly the same amount of code as the C version would use
```

If you really want I'll provide a C example but this is getting overly long

EDIT: I saw below that it has to be C compatible. So I'll expand to include the C equivalent of that last code and also include passing by reference. Keep in mind this is conceptual: it will compile but it isn't very useful.

C:

```
/* This is a generic object. It has a type ID and a pointer, that is all that is needed. It can hold anything. */
struct generic_holder {
  int type;
  void *ptr;
};

/* This is an example struct it may point to. */
struct holder_one {
  int a;
  int b;
  float c;
  char *d;
  int change_this;
};

/* This is another example struct. */
struct holder_two {
  char best[50];
  char worst[50];
  int change_this;
};

struct stuff_s {
/*    ...in .o */
  generic_holder data;
};

/* Forward-declaration */
void set_to_four(stuff_s *foo);

/* Later on... */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  stuff_s foo;
  holder_two test_struct = { "C++", "Lisp", 0 };  // Best, worst. Haha.

  foo.o.data.ptr = (void *)&test_struct; /* This makes it into a "generic pointer" by casting it to void */

  foo.o.data.type = 2; /* = 2 because we are using holder_two */

  /* We're going to use our function to set data in a generic object, passing by reference. This would work equally well on something of type holder_one, and can be expanded for data types you haven't thought of. */
  set_to_four(&foo);

  return 0;
}

/* This function will take a generic object and set the 'change_this' variable to 4 */
void set_to_four(stuff_s *foo)
{
  holder_one *ptr1;
  holder_two *ptr2;

  if (foo == NULL) return;            /* Obsessively check for invalid pointers */
  assert(foo.o.data.ptr != NULL);     /* Some people prefer to do checks only in debug, for speed. This does the same thing but only if debug is on. And it stops the program when it gets there if there is an error. It evaluates to nothing if it's a release build. */

  switch(foo.o.data.type) {
    case 1:
      ptr1 = (holder_one *)foo.o.data.ptr;
      ptr1->change_this = 4;
      break;
    case 2:
      ptr2 = (holder_two *)foo.o.data.ptr;
      ptr2->change_this = 4;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `if (what) what->o.s = 4;`

Comment: @hochl NULL is not guaranteed to be 0, even though in practically every implementation it is.

Comment: @OrgnlDave - true, but `if(ptr)` is true if and only if ptr is not NULL.

Comment: @Robᵩthat's really guaranteed? I have some housecleaning to do if so. can you point me at some documentation?

Comment: @OrgnlDave: for C++03 see 6.4/3 "The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the expression, implicitly converted to bool".  A null pointer value converts to `false` any other pointer value converts to `true` (C++03 4.12).  For C see C99 6.8.4.1/2: "the ﬁrst substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0".  So any `if` condition is essentially equivalent to `if ((condition) != 0)`. And since by definition `0` is the null pointer constant, you have an implicit test for the null pointer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I take that back. Indeed, C++03 does say that any pointer that is invalid will evaluate to a false bool. Thanks and good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you put some accessors in your struct, you can safely change the implementation of the struct tomorrow without affecting any other code.

For example,

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int getVal() {return val;}
    int val;
}
```

As for the other half of the question, Im afraid theres no straight forward answer. You should try both and test it out for yourself.

I notice that you think it is "easier" to have the additional bytes, If you are talking about typing, this is not really true, as you can use bitfields, that is

```
struct MyStruct
{
    unsigned val1 : 10; // val1 is 10 bits long
    unsigned val2 : 3;  // val2 is 3 bits big
};

// access values
MyStruct s;
s.val1 = ...;
```

Furthermore, function calling wont be "slowed down" by the size of what's passed in if you pass a const ref into it rather than by value. That is:

```
void foo( const MyStruct & myStruct)
{ 
//eg: myStruct.val1 = 10; // your code here 
}
```

As for your new "actual question"

It wont affect the speed much unless its in an inner loop somewhere. Rule of thumb is to pass by const ref, and think about optimization when your program is actually too slow

Comment: Awesome thanks, but this all just needs to be C-compatible. =)
Also, aren't bit fields a big big pain to use?

Comment: Not at all, its quite painless

Comment: @imacake oh, C compatible? I will expand my answer if you want the C version of the generic base class/derived thingy.